# Spring Cloud Gateway Simple example not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

Most basic Spring Cloud Gateway app not working.

application.yml

```
server:
    port: 9000
```

GatewayApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("test", r -> r.path("/test")
                        .uri("http://httpbin.org:80"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Postman: http://localhost:9000/test

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL         
manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Postman:  http://localhost:9000/test2

```
{
   "timestamp": "2019-06-26T22:24:34.208+0000",
   "path": "/test2",
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "message": null
}
```

Answer (score 5):

#### http://localhost:9000/test

Your first request will be send to `http://httpbin.org:80/test`. And Because there is no request mapping for `/test` in http://httpbin.org, You got 404 Not Found response from http://httpbin.org.

---

#### http://localhost:9000/test2

Your second request will not be sent anywhere. "/test2" cannot be sent, because your route config is "/test". So you got 404 Not Found response from your gateway application. If you want to apply same routing rule to "/test2", your config have to be "/test**"

Answer (score 4):

You dont have any url like http://httpbin.org/test and hence the 404

Answer (score -1):

Remove these two properties if available

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true
```